# WordPress Multisite Network Subdomain

Tags: multisite, user-registration, subdomains

I want to start something, but before i do it i'm asking for some advice.
 the scenario is.....
mywebsite.com 
 i will have listing directories and i want for every category to use a different theme, like

automobile/mywebsite.com automobile theme
food/mywebsite.com food theme
education/mywebsite.com education theme
other/mywebsite.com some other theme

is it possible  that, when "user1" comes to "automobile/mywebsite.com" makes new registration  and in the same time is registered to all subdomains. so when "user1" comes to  "food/mywebsite.com" is already registered or to any other subdomain.

is something like this possible ?

Regards.

Comment: [Yes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/join-my-multisite/)

Comment: This is not possible in the default of a Multiiste. But you can enhance via plugin, so that users get access to alles Sites of the network. Like this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/join-my-multisite/ (but more functions, code etc.) or custom source via function `add_user_to_blog`.

Comment: Your URLs look weird -- do you mean `mywebsite.com/automobile` instead of `automobile/mywebsite.com`? I don't think the latter is a well-formed URL.

Comment: thanks for replaying to my question.
yes, we can use mywebsite.com/automobile, mywebsite.com/food and soo on, now i have another little problem, about the search, when visitor is at mywebsite.com/automobile and the visitor wants to search about food, well in my case food is in another website, is there a plugin that can make it happen that it searches all the domains ? i'm a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using https://wordpress.org/plugins/network-subsite-user-registration/

this was developed for the situation where you have the flexibility to open or close user registration on any sitesite of a network. It should be the ticket.